# JQuery/Ajax page load on a php datagrid for a perticular record id

Tags: php, jquery

I'm creating a data-list in php using php and ajax page load same like redbus.in, i'm new to php and jquery and ajax.

I want when I will click the button 'view seat' a ajax page load will happen with dynamic data.

I am using Jquery to achive this using below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#viewseatContainer").hide();
$(document).ready(function() {

     $("#viewseat").click(function(){
     $("#viewseatContainer").toggle();
     });
 });
```

But in my datalist only the first item is showing the view seat information

in my PHP

```
echo ...

'<td id="abc"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:ajaxpage(\'view.php?id='.$_SESSION['$bus_id'].'
,&from='.$_SESSION['$bus_startstation'].',&to='.$_SESSION['$bus_endstation'].' 
,&date='.$_SESSION['date'].' \' , \'viewseatContainer\')">
<img src="themes/frontend/images/redbtn.png" width="100" height="32" id="viewseat" /></a></td>'.
'<td>ID:'.$_SESSION['$bus_id'].'</td>'.
```

For Ajax page load i'm using a simple plugins

My question is I have viewseatContainer and id= viewseat using Jquery how can I toggle each or any records to load view.php using ajax page load.

For more clarity I had given my full code in paste bin

http://pastebin.com/dB8STTSR (jquery)

http://pastebin.com/Raa5TJCG  (datagrid)

Comment: Firstly, ID's are unique and should only be used once, so jQuery will only perform actions on the first one it finds, to toggle multiple elements use a class instead.

Comment: It has multiple Id for example viewseat and viewseat2 so how can I add a class using jquery for abstract viewseat ids?

Can it be done using Passing php arrays to jquery arrays?

Comment: I tried with .bind function but its only working for the first record not below

$("#viewseatContainer").hide();
 
    $("#viewseat").bind("click", function() {
     $("#viewseatContainer").toggle();
 });

Answer (score 0):

Kureshu First do one thing

Use this Jquery

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#viewseatContainer").hide();
var x = <?php echo $_SESSION['$bus_id']?>;
$.each(x, function (i, elem) {
    $("#" +'viewseatContainer' + x).toggle();
});
 });
 </script>
```

Then go to your PHP Code Page (second pastebib one as you given) then add bus id to the AJAX load container also like this below

```
'<tr>'.
'<td>'.$_SESSION['$travel_name'].'</td>'.
'<td><a href="#">Photogallary</a></td>'.
'<td><a href="#">Via</a></td>'.
'<td id="abc"><a href="#" onclick="javascript:ajaxpage(\'view.php?id='.$_SESSION['$bus_id'].'&from='.$_SESSION['$bus_startstation'].'&to='.$_SESSION['$bus_endstation'].'&date='.$_SESSION['date'].'\',\'viewseatContainer'.$_SESSION['$bus_id'].'\')"><img src="themes/frontend/images/redbtn.png" width="100" height="32" id="'.$_SESSION['$bus_id'].'" /></a></td>'.
'<td>ID:'.$_SESSION['$bus_id'].'</td>'.
'</tr>'.
'<tr>'.
'<td colspan="6" id="vsc">'.
'<div id="viewseatContainer'.$_SESSION['$bus_id'].'"></div>'.
'</td>'.
'</tr>'
```

and remember one things as the  viewseatContainer has multiple instances you can hide this a class not here

```
 $("#viewseatContainer").hide();// use a class to hide
```

Now you're ready to go...

Comment: Yes now I can able to multiple viewseat to my container but toggling is not working, by the way it is helpful.

Comment: Use JSON in your second pastbin and then access the array
var x= <?php echo json_encode($bus_id) ?>;

Comment: Ok, I have done this and I hope it will works for you. Just remove the Jquery from First pastebin file and use this jQuery directly.

http://pastebin.com/Hzb2kSQR